# Facebook - interests required List<unsigned int32> although Page ID are strings

Tags: facebook, video

I currently developed a solution for custom uploading videos for specific customers.
One of my customers need the ability to specify "interests" for a video he upload.

From the API documentation, interests are:

interests
list
One or more IDs of pages to target fans of pages.Use type of page to get possible IDs as find Targeting Options and use the returned id to specify.

There is some mis-documentation regarding this feature: "find Targeting Options" does not talks about type=page.
But, still, I can search for page, using the "search" endpoint: /2.5/search?q=gsw&type=page and get the ID of the page.

As to my understanding, I can specify a page, for example "Golden State Warriors" fan page, specify its id, and then every user which follows this page will be considered as interested in my post.

So, I think my flow should be:
 1) Search for the requested page using the "search" api. Get the page's IDS.
 2) When creating the video, specify the ID in the "interests" parameter list.

Now, I need to know how to specify the ID in the interests list - The documentation says it list, but the page ID as a number string...

So in conclusion, I would like some help in verifying that all that I have written is correct and make sense, and also to know how to get the int32 id of a page - is it just mistake in the documentaion?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide links to the documentation that you have used for this?

Comment: Hi @Shmulik, did you ever figure this out? I'm able to get the string id's for "interests" but having trouble mapping those to the actual, human readable name.